# jQuery loop over all td in a table

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to loop over a table to select all the td and change the color to white

```
   j$('#accessSml1 tr').each(function(){
    j$(this).find('td').each(function(){
        //alert('hi');
        //document.getElementById(j$(this)).style.backgroundColor = ''; 
        j$(this).style.backgroundColor = ''; 
    })
   })
```

I am not sure how to adress the td we are in to change the background color.
Have tried a few options as shown above.

```
TypeError: j$(...).style is undefined
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
j$('#accessSml1 tr td').css('background-color','white')
```

Comment: Simple, perfect & rapid response. Thanks so much

Comment: Glad I could help. If you need me to explain it let me know.